# Differential equation $y' = ky(M-y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like some help with an assignment about differential equations. This is the question as stated:

Duckburg has $10,000$ ducks. One year, Duckburg is affected by a contagious disease. All ducks who become infected, remain infected throughout the year before they miraculously recover at the beginning of the next year. The disease spreads so that the increase (change) in the number of infected always is proportional to the product of the number of infected and the number of non-infected. Let y (t) be the number of infected ducks t days after the beginning of the year. At the beginning of the year there are 10 ducks infected, and 30 days later 100 are infected.

Explain in text how this can be written mathematically as:

$$y'=ky(M-y)$$

where $k$ is a constant. What is this constant usually called?

I am having trouble categorizing and solving it, and connecting it to $dP/dt = rP(1−P/K)$. Any help would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To begin with, I would start by noticing that it is a separable ODE

\begin{align*}
y' = ky(M - y) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y'}{y(M-y)} = k \Longleftrightarrow \int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(M-y)} = \int k\mathrm{d}x = kx + c
\end{align*}

Then we can rewrite the LHS by
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y(M-y)} = \frac{M}{My(M-y)} = \frac{(M - y) + y}{My(M-y)} = \frac{1}{My} + \frac{1}{M(M-y)} 
\end{align*}

which can be easily integrated. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I manged to get this: (ln(y)/M)-(ln(y-M)/M=kc+C, nut i am unsure of what to do from here...

Comment: I have got:
y=5000+sqrt{e^{10000(kx+c}+25000000}
y=5000-sqrt{e^{10000(kx+c}+25000000}

Answer (score 0):

$$y'=ky(M-y)$$
Note that $y=0$ is a solution of this DE. This is Bernoulli's differential equation:
$$y'-kMy=-ky^2$$
$$(ye^{-kMx})'=-ky^2e^{-kMx}$$
$$\dfrac {(ye^{-kMx})'}{y^2e^{-2kMx}}=-ke^{kMx}$$
$$\dfrac {d(ye^{-kMx})}{(ye^{-kMx})^2}=-ke^{kMx} \; dx$$
Integrate.

---

I am having trouble categorizing and solving it, and connecting it to $dP/dt=rP(1−P/K)$. Any help would be nice :)

$$dP/dt=rP(1−P/K)$$
$$\dfrac d {dt}\left( \dfrac PK \right)=r\dfrac PK \left(1−\dfrac PK\right)$$
$$y'=ry(1-y)$$
Where $y=\dfrac PK, r=k,M=1$.

Comment: Thank You! I see now where i went wrong! When i plug in the numbers I get: y=5000+sqrt{e^{10000(kx+c}+25000000} 
y=5000-sqrt{e^{10000(kx+c}+25000000}